# Bootstrap container-build not filling the screen even with p-0

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, containers

For screens, I put padding at 0 for container-fluid but the screen still does not fill the screen that is less than or equal to width 1024.

```
.container-fluid {
    background-color: #e2e5f4;
    height: 600px; 
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

What works: 
at 1024-  width: 101%; 
at 768-   width: 112%; 
at 320-   width: 112%;

HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row border bg-danger p-0">
        <div class="col-md-7  p-0">
        <div class="MededX"> 
                MEDedX
        </div>
        <div class="capture_tittle">
            liunhliunh
            <br> lunliu luinu liuni 
            <br> nllniun Nilo ahh
        </div>

        <div class="subCapture_tittle">
            LOerm Swaminarayan swmainarayan swaminarayan swaminarayan                        

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 p-0 ">

        <div>
            <img class= "hex" src="hex.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class= "medIpad" src="medipad.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class= "plantsLeft" src="plantsLeft.png">
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

What's the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom wrapper and set its width to 100%.

```
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

or a fast solution

```
style="width:100%"
```

Comment: No I still don't understand why container-fluid doesn't work

Comment: what is the version of your bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using chrome inspect to check for iPhone X. It might be the zoom. How do I know it's the write zoom for each device? When I zoom in, it saves when I switch devices

Comment: and bootstrap 4

Comment: @j.doe 1) for zoom: on device `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
`

Comment: see in the documentation of Bootstrap 4: [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

Comment: no no I'm talking about zoom on Chrome inspect where it allows you to choose different devices and zoom in and out. I don't know if I'm zoomed in or zoomed out. Maybe that is why my container fluid does not fit

Comment: your question was another, my solution is good. so you have another problem.

Comment: **My container fluid may fit but I just don't know because I'm zoomed out

Comment: @j.doe the problems of zooming can be many, tell me how I can help?

Comment: Thank you I solved it. I have another problem. I have  2 columns in a row with bootstrap 4. On the left it is an image and on the right is some texted relating to that image. With mobile view the image on the right goes to the top. How do I get the left column  to go to the bottom and the right to go above that?